# CoreData: Light-weight migration from xcdatamodel version n to n+5

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Let’s say a user has **MyApp2.xcdatamodel** installed on their iPhone and that they have not upgraded their app for a while. Now the current version of the app uses **MyApp7.xcdatamodel**. Will the ligthweight migration mechanism be able to migrate smoothly the data to the current model?

My assumption is yes as long as **MyApp3**.xcdatamodel, **MyApp4**.xcdatamodel, **MyApp5**.xcdatamodel and **MyApp6**.xcdatamodel are available.

Can anyone confirm this assumption?

Thanks in advance,

Joss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. As long as you have all the models in your project this will work.